# Falta traducir una sección de Herramientas de Revisión

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

En la pagina [Herramientas de Revision](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools) existe el siguiente texto sin traducir en la sección enlaces:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El texto debería ser Preguntas Protegidas

Ingresando al enlace, en la página [Protected Questions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tools/protected-questions) tambien existe texto sin traducir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería ser:

- Preguntas Protegidas
- n Preguntas
- Fecha de la pregunta, Protegida por, Protegida la fecha, # Respuestas de los últimos 30 días, # Respuestas eliminadas

Answer (score 3):

Se ha actualizado este texto. Gracias por la notificación.

Comment: Faltó agregar la etiqueta [meta-tag:estado-completado]